# Out of bounds error in a loop

Tags: loops, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public static void bubbleSort(Farm a[], int n) {
String[] animals = getString(a);

for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)  {

  boolean swapped = false;
  for(int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {

    int c = animals[j].compareTo(animals[j+1]);
    if(c > 0) {
      swap(animals, j, j+1);
      swapped = true;
    }
  }
  if(!swapped) 
    break;
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  if(a[i] != null)
  System.out.println(a[i].animal);
```

}

in int c = animals[j].compareTo(animals[j+1]); it is giving me an out of bounds error for some reason

Comment: What is `n` in this context? Is it the count of objects in `a`? If so, on the first iteration of the loop, `j+1` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `n >= animals.length`

Check boundary values in the `for` loops again